# win32com raises error when trying to use ShowDetail in PivotField()

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I am using a python script to add new data to an excel document and then build a pivot table with these data every time it is called.

For creating the pivot I am using win32com to build the pivot, but since the data set is way too large, I am trying to collapse the table based on a specific field.

The collapse happens without problems when applying

```
ShowDetail = False
```

as in

```
PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIRECTION").PivotItems("IN").ShowDetail = False
```

But since the dataset is very large, I was trying to set it for the whole field, like

```
 PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIRECTION").ShowDetail = False
```

which raises the error

```
AttributeError: win32com.gen_py.unknown.PivotItems instance at 0x149903408  object has no attribute 'ShowDetail'
```

Currently using Python 3.6 in Anaconda, with pywin32 version 220, as it came preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Try using index for PivotItem, work's for me:

```
for item in range(1,PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIRECTION").PivotItems().Count+1): 
PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIRECTION").PivotItems(item).ShowDetail = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you but I looped through the items. I am using Python 2.7 though so the syntax might differ a bit. Here is the code I used

```
for item in PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DIRECTION").PivotItems:
    item.ShowDetail = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only the following code:

```
wbs2.PivotTables(pvt_name).PivotFields('Years').ShowDetail = False
```

It's working for me.